# Need the output of the inputs to be pushed into the <div>

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, verification

I'm trying to get the user inputs to be pushed out as a message into a `<div>` via the button press after confirming that all the inputs are filled and the correct password has been entered. That part works fine but my `forEach` is not working:

If the user has input a number value lower than 18, I want an `if` that types out via push *"Your name is `UName` and you are `Age` years old, you are not of legal age"*, or else the same result as above but ending with *"...you are of legal age"*.

Any idea how I should go forth?

```js
let nameElement = document.getElementById("UNameInput");
let faultElement = document.getElementById("errorOutput");
let ageElement = document.getElementById("AgeInput");
let clickElement = document.getElementById("button");
let passwordElement = document.getElementById("PasswordInput");
clickElement.addEventListener("click", function(e) {

  let feedback = [];
  if (UNameInput.value === '' || UNameInput.value === null) {
    feedback.push('Name input missing')
  }

  if (AgeInput.value === '' || AgeInput.value === null) {
    feedback.push('Age input missing')
  } else if (PasswordInput.value !== 'IHM') {
    feedback.push('Password is not valid')
  } else {
    feedback.forEach((item, i) => {
      if (item.AgeInput < 18) {
        feedback.push("You are not of not legal age")
      } else {
        feedback.push(" You are of legal age ")
      }
    });
  }
  if (feedback.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault()
    faultElement.innerText = feedback.join(", ")
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="JSny.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="errorOutput"></div>
  <p id="output"></p>
  <div>
    <label for="UNameInput">Name Input</label>
    <input id="UNameInput" name="name" type="text">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="AgeInput">Age Input</label>
    <input id="AgeInput" name="age" type="number">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="PasswordInput">Password Input</label>
    <input id="PasswordInput" name="password" type="password">
  </div>
  <button id="button">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using AgeInput instead of ageElement in the if statement.

Comment: Changed to the above, and still no response when pressing the button.